Transfer/Stream data/CSV Files from POS (Point of sales) to GCS Buckets and then to Big query
I am working on a project where I have to transfer/Stream the data/CSV file from on prem POS to GCS buckets and then data will be first saved to Big Query external table and then moved to other presentation layer tables (Medallion architecture) thru dataflow jobs for the consumption thru looker studio. I am thinking of below flow -
Step 1. POS to GCS Bucket ( Thru Storage transfer Service?)
Step 2. GCS buckets will be connected to BigQuery external tables
Step 3. Data will move to another layer (Big query) thru dataflow jobs
Step 4. Big query (Presentation layer) will feed the looker studio reports
All the data is streaming data or near Realtime data in csv files
Can someone please answer the following -
Question 2 - What is the best way to transfer/stream data (CSV files) from On Prem POS (Point of sales) to GCS buckets?
Question 2 - In Step 1, Is storage transfer service is good enough to transfer/stream POS data to GCS buckets as CSV files? or do I need pub/sub also? How will it take care of incremental ingestion.
Question 3 - Does Big Query external tables automatically reflect the data in table as soon as they have a file entered in the GCS buckets?
Questions 4 - How to do incremental ingestion from one layer to another. Does dataflow support incremental ingestion for streaming data?
Question 5 - How to work out data security and data privacy in Big query table?
Thanks

Wow, you are asking for a complete data platform ingestion pipeline! In fact, too many questions.... One of my biggest advice is not to perform streaming with GCS. If you do this, the CRC is not checked and you can have data alteration. If you have transaction data in your POS CSV file, it could be dramatic! prefer small chunks, or transaction per transaction transfer through pubsub. I also recommend to avoid dataflow and prefer SQL in bigquery to transform/clean data. Finally, about the delta mode, use transaction timestamp in your CSV to achieve it.

Oh, and yes, all the files that match the external table pattern are read when you start your query.

Can you please explain if I have to transfer the data from on Prem SQL server to GCS storage as CSV files. How do I achieve it for real time or near realtime?

You have a SQL server? In that case, I strongly recommend using datastream https://cloud.google.com/datastream?hl=en and avoid CVS and file transfer to GCS

Can you please clarify below - 1. Cloud SQL (SQL Server) to GCS using DataStream using CDC - Do I need Pub/Sub for it?     2. Does Datastream support On Prem Oracle DB to GCS? Would CDC work in that case and do we need Pub/Sub for it. My requirement is to stream data Realtime from both sources to GCS/Bigquery. I want to use GCS because there is a third source which post files in GCS therefore I thought of using external tables. Please clarify

What you mean by CRC. Did you mean CDC? Can CDC not enable in datastream to stream the data to GCS?

CRC: Control Error Checksum. File integrity check. CDC (Change Data Capture) is able to catch event in your source database (on prem) and replicate data in BigQuery. Like that, you can avoid the file structure and storage in GCS. Much more efficient
